# Assimp skeletal animation becomes a triangle mess

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, assimp

I've been trying to animate a model in OpenGl using Assimp.
The result of my attempts is 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxasv.png).

Loading bones:

```
List<Bone> getBones(AIMesh mesh) {
    List<Bone> bones = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < mesh.mNumBones(); i++) {
        AIBone aiBone = AIBone.create(mesh.mBones().get(i));
        Bone bone = new Bone(aiBone.mName().dataString());
        bone.setOffset(aiMatrixToMatrix(aiBone.mOffsetMatrix()).transpose());
        bones.add(bone);
    }
    return bones;
}
```

Loading vertices:

```
VertexData processVertices(AIMesh mesh) {
    float[] weights = null;
    int[] boneIds = null;
    float[] vertices = new float[mesh.mNumVertices() * 3];
    boolean calculateBones = mesh.mNumBones() != 0;

    if (calculateBones) {
        weights = new float[mesh.mNumVertices() * 4];
        boneIds = new int[mesh.mNumVertices() * 4];
    }

    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    for (AIVector3D vertex : mesh.mVertices()) {
        vertices[i++] = vertex.x();
        vertices[i++] = vertex.y();
        vertices[i++] = vertex.z();

        //bone data if any
        if (calculateBones) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mesh.mNumBones(); j++) {
                AIBone bone = AIBone.create(mesh.mBones().get(j));
                for (AIVertexWeight weight : bone.mWeights()) {
                    if (weight.mVertexId() == i - 3) {
                        k++;
                        boneIds[k] = j;
                        weights[k] = weight.mWeight();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong.
Are all the matrices required for the bind pose or can I use only the offset for testing?

Answer (score 0):

If I get you code right you do not get the inidecs by the faces, right? You need to iterate over the faces of your mesh to get the correct inidices, if I get the concept you are using right.